# Hygroscopic substances

Tags: antonyms

The terms 'desiccant' and 'humectant' are opposites of each other. However, both of them have been described as 'hygroscopic' substances. If desiccant and humectant are opposites of each other, how come both of them are hygroscopic?

Answer (score 3):

I think this comes into the ambiguity of "opposites", the actual molecules will function similarly - they create low energy bonds with water, thereby drawing out water from adjacent fluids/surfaces. The difference is where they are used.

A desiccant is placed **in the same container** as what is supposed to be kept dry. It therefore absorbs water **away** from the object.

A humectant is placed   **on the surface** of what is supposed to be kept wet. Or in the case of food additives **inside** the food. This draws water **into** a desired area.

They are opposites because the usage results in the opposite effect occurring with respect to the desired good, as opposed to the actual substance.

Comment: Very good answer, we could also say that 'hygroscopic' is a description of the nature of the substance whereas 'dessicant' and 'humectant' are descriptions of the use to which it is put.